# PHP Count the number of times a value appears in result

Tags: php

I'm selecting data from a database:

```
$status = "Attended";
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM jobstocomplete WHERE applicant_mid=:mID AND status=:status');

$query->execute(array(':mID' => $mID, ':status' => $status));
```

I then put the results into a table using a while loop such as below:

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {

  echo "<div class='panel-body table-responsive'>";
  echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
  echo "<thead>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th id=''>Job ID</th>";
  echo "<th id=''>Total</th>";
  echo "<th id=''>Company Name</th>";
  echo "<th id=''>Action</th>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</thead>";
  echo "<tbody>";

  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $companyname = $row['compname'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['jobid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['total'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($companyname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";

    $completed = $row['compl'];

    if (empty($completed)) {
      echo  "<td>" . "<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Not yet complete' disabled>Mark as completed</button></a>" . "</td>";
    }else{
      echo  "<td>" . "<a class='btn custombtn' href='#invoiceModal' data-toggle='modal' data-jid='".htmlspecialchars($row["jobid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-mid='".htmlspecialchars($row["applicant_mid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-upid='".htmlspecialchars($row["up_id"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."'> Mark as completed</a>" . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}else{
  echo "<p>Looks like you've not completed any jobs</p>";
}
```

When my users click "Mark as Complete" this then launches a bootstrap modal which then triggers jQuery/ajax to generate an invoice using fpdf.

What I am wanting to achieve is calculate the number of times a company name appears. For example if among the results `$companyname = "Heaven Autos"` appears more than once I want my code to launch a different modal which will alert

"Do you want to generate a multiple invoice as you have carried out more than one job for this company"

This will then trigger a different php files using jQuery/ajax and calculate total etc and generate an invoice based on that.

I invisaged doing this running a query and a simple if statement but didn't know how to start the logic.

I hope this makes sense and I hope you can help.

p.s I have already tried things like array_count etc and haven't had much luck, any advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered adding an ID data attribute and in your modal trigger loop through all the IDs and if length > 1 trigger the second modal? You basically need an identifier either data attribute or unique class for each entry that you can check before your trigger with this kind of logic

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment, I've modded your PHP code slightly with this:

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {

          echo "<div class='panel-body table-responsive'>";
          echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
          echo "<thead>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<th id=''>Job ID</th>";
          echo "<th id=''>Total</th>";
          echo "<th id=''>Company Name</th>";
          echo "<th id=''>Action</th>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "</thead>";
          echo "<tbody>";

          while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

          $companyname = $row['compname'];

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['jobid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['total'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($companyname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "</td>";

          $completed = $row['compl'];

          if (empty($completed)) {
            echo  "<td>" . "<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Not yet complete' disabled>Mark as completed</button></a>" . "</td>";
          }else{
            echo  "<td>" . "<a class='btn custombtn' href='#invoiceModal' data-toggle='modal' data-company='" . htmlspecialchars($companyname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') . "' data-jid='".htmlspecialchars($row["jobid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-mid='".htmlspecialchars($row["applicant_mid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-upid='".htmlspecialchars($row["up_id"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."'> Mark as completed</a>" . "</td>";
          }

          echo "</tr>";

          }

}else{
              echo "<p>Looks like you've not completed any jobs</p>";
}
```

The change here is I've added a data-company attribute to your modal trigger, this way each company's name is stored within an attribute in the modal trigger as you generate them.

Now here's the JS to go along when that button is clicked:

```
<script>
    // clicking the button begins here
    $('.custombtn').click(function() {
        // set the count variable to zero, we'll check how many companies exist and add it to the counter 
        var count = 0;
        // grab the clicked button's company name in the data attribute
        var xid = $(this).attr('data-company');
        // loop through all the buttons by class and check the data-company attribute for our count
        $(".custombtn").each(function(index) {
            // store each button's data company attribute for our logic
            var co = $(this).attr('data-company');
            // we check if the currently clicked button's company matches any of the companies that exists in our table
            if (co == xid) {
                // if we have a match, we add one to our counter
                count = count + 1;
            }
        });
        // at the end of the loop, we now check the results of our count
        if (count > 1) {
            // count is greater than 1, so we can trigger a multi-company action
            console.log('we got two or more matches');
        } else {
            // count is  1, so we can trigger a single company action
            console.log('we got one match');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I commented each step so you can easily see the logic and function;

What we're basically doing is when the button is clicked, we take that button's data-company attribute value with the company name which we set in our PHP; we loop through all the buttons by the class identifier and check each button's data-company attribute; now for each result we have a counter variable that increments with each match so we can check the counter if our results are 1 or more;

When you get your result, you can mod this code to store additional data- attributes to follow up with triggering any custom actions you'd like such as triggering two seperate modals, making two ajax calls, displaying different alerts or notifications; whatever you wish to do.

Comment: genuinely appreciate your time and effort to answer the question, but the counter doesn't seem to be working. i.e I have "Heaven Autos" appear 6 times but the console only shows "We got one match" - your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should count company name AT SQL level not in JS/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had a light bulb moment and achieved this adding the below query to my while loop to count the number of times companyname exists in my table with conditions:

```
$sqll = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM jobstocomplete WHERE compname=:companyname AND applicant_mid=:mID AND status=:status"); 
          $sqll->execute(array(':companyname' => $companyname,':mID' => $mID, ':status' => $status2)); 
          $number_of_rows = $sqll->fetchColumn();
```

I then did a if statement and launched the appropriate modal accordingly:

```
if (empty($completed)) {
            echo  "<td>" . "<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Job not yet completed'><button class='btn custombtn' disabled>Mark as completed</button></a>" . "</td>";
          }else if(!empty($completed) && $number_of_rows > 1){
            echo  "<td>" . "<a id='genInvoiceBtn' class='btn custombtn' href='#multiinvoiceModal' data-toggle='modal' data-company='".htmlspecialchars($companyname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-jid='".htmlspecialchars($row["jobid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-mid='".htmlspecialchars($row["applicant_mid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-upid='".htmlspecialchars($row["up_id"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."'> Mark as completed</a>" . "</td>";
          }else if(!empty($completed) && $number_of_rows < 1){
            echo  "<td>" . "<a id='genInvoiceBtn' class='btn custombtn' href='#invoiceModal' data-toggle='modal' data-company='".htmlspecialchars($companyname, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-jid='".htmlspecialchars($row["jobid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-mid='".htmlspecialchars($row["applicant_mid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."' data-upid='".htmlspecialchars($row["up_id"], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')."'> Mark as completed</a>" . "</td>";
          }
```